# Genexus 17 u0 Error ejectuando app en dispositivo con android 11

Tags: android, genexus

Tengo un aplicación Android generada en Genexus 17 upgrade 0 con GAM que al abrirla en un dispositivo con Android 11 se queda cargando sin mostrar el login.

La misma aplicación es compatible con dispositivos con Android < 11.

Entre los errores que vi en el logcat estan:

```
2021-08-11 11:44:01.146 12804-12856/com.artech.nettest17.sdpanelmenu W/DefaultRequestDirector: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="192.168.68.102"} 

2021-08-11 11:44:01.153 563-914/system_process I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {flg=0x80000 cmp=com.artech.nettest17.sdpanelmenu/com.artech.activities.GenexusActivity (has extras)} from uid 10155 

2021-08-11 11:44:01.153 563-609/system_process D/EventSequenceValidator: Transition from INTENT_FAILED to INTENT_STARTED 2021-08-11  11:44:01.161 363-363/?> E/perfetto: ing_service_impl.cc:605 Too many concurrent tracing sesions (5) for uid 1071 limit is 5 

2021-08-11 11:44:01.162 369-1086/? E/perfetto: r_api_deprecated.cc:216 Tracing session failed 2021-08-11 11:44:01.167 369-26961/? E/iorapd: Perfetto trace proto collection error: kTraceFailed
```

Este bloque de errores se repite mientras tengo la app abierta cargando.

Probe las opciones del este [link](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?29368,App%20Transport%20Security%20property%20group) habilitando el acceso a mi host, pero no sigue sin cargar.

Hasta con dispositivos con android 10 funcionan bien y enseguida que la abro me lleva al login.

El login del GAM es de validación local, no se conecta con nada externo.

La aplicación no tiene ninguna funcionalidad compleja ni requiere permisos extras, es una app de prueba con un Menu y un llamado a un Work With.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes verificar si el problema no se corresponde al [SAC #48582](https://www2.genexusnet.com/gxpintranet/hgxpp001.aspx?1,14,132,O,S,0,,48582) ?

Esta solucionado en v17u1 o superior y también esta en v17u0HF.
Además te recomiendo usar v17u2 o superior que es donde entro el [soporte completo de Android 11](https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/rn?data=0;4;V17;2;V17;1;;).

Gracias,

Comment: Impecable era eso si. Migre los proyectos a la u4 y me anduvieron bien. Gracias